# How was Captain Archer captured by the Klingons?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In Star Trek episode [ENT: Judgment](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Judgment_(episode)), Captain Archer is put on trial by the Klingons. The episode begins with the trial and, as far as I remember, it is not shown or even mentioned how has the Captain ended in Klingon's custody.

Have I omitted anything in the episode or has it been simply waived? Any out-of-episode information?

Answer (score 3):

Having listened to the [audio commentary for the episode](https://trekcore.com/blog/2014/02/star-treks-lost-audio-commentaries-judgment-north-star-and-star-trek-the-motion-picture/) and David A. Goodman's own synopsis for [Federation: The First 150 Years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Federation_-_The_First_150_Years), I think we can conclude that this is something that has been left *intentionally vague*. The conceit seems to be that he was captured when he was off the Enterprise, but beyond that there's no mention of how this occurred.

---

> Jonathan Archer had several run-ins with Klingons, but the most serious was his intervention to help the Arin'Sen. They were a subject species of the Empire, and Archer succeeded in helping a ship of Arin'Sen refugees escape a Klingon ship's pursuit. **Archer was eventually captured for this "crime,"** tried on the Klingon colony of Narendra III, and sentenced to life imprisonment on the penal asteroid Rura Penthe. He escaped, but the Klingons responded by putting a bounty on him, which technically was never lifted throughout his life.
>
> <sub><sup>[Federation: The First 150 Years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Federation_-_The_First_150_Years)</sup></sub>

and

> *"As I was breaking the story I thought that this [the initial scene
> with Archer and Phlox] was a great way to get the exposition out that
> Archer had been captured and taken by the Klingons and that that
> Enterprise was there for the trial"*
>
> <sub><sup>Audio Commentary - Judgement with David A. Goodman</sup></sub>